# How to rename the advanced search link in magento 2

Tags: magento2, advanced-search

Can anyone help.. i wanted to change the "advanced search" to "finder". How to rename it via xml??

Comment: at which point are you want to show label?

Comment: I wanted to just change the text from advanced search to finder

Comment: At the header near search

Comment: I am using ubuntu os.. it runs well on windows.. why not in ubuntu??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code in following code in following file.

**app/design/frontend/vendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog-search-advanced-link">
            <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Finder</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">catalogsearch/advanced</argument>
             </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>       
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: you need to add path catalogsearch/advanced instead of catalogsearch/finder

Comment: Updated `catalogsearch/advanced`.

Comment: Its not working! !can u help me out

Comment: It should work. Because it is tested code. It may be, these links are managing from static blocks

Answer (score 0):

Just create `en_US.csv`(I am assuming you have this locale if you have another then replace with another) file in below path

`app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme name}/i18n/en_US.csv`

```
"Advanced Search","Finder"
```

And then execute below command,

```
php bin/magento s:s:d
php bin/magento c:f
```

Comment: I tried but its not changing.. will there be any file permission issues?